# Endeca Dimensions not showing up in Workbench to be reordered?

Tags: endeca-workbench

We've got 2 dimensions that have values that are not showing up in workbench under the Dimension Order tab.

The top level settings for each are: sorted by "Alpha", not members of another dimension

General tab: "Show with record list" and "Show with record" checked, default language search in dropdown

Search tab: Nothing checked

Advanced tab: "Compute refinement statistics" checked, Multiselect: None

Dynamic Ranking tab: Nothing checked

Cluster Discovery: Nothing checked

These are the exact same settings as several other dimensions which do show up in workbench.  Is there some other setting we should be looking for?